# Is there a switch like gui element other than radio buttons in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am looking for a switch like gui element in Qt. It actually exists when [using QML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/declarative-ui-components-slideswitch.html) but I would like to stay away from QML with the project in concern. I simply need to switch between two alternatives so radio buttons are not very appropriate. 
The gui should look like this (not exactly but to make it more clear)

```
 [A o--|    B] 

 [A    |--o B]
```

Comment: You could use a trackbar for the approximate look, but that's really not the right tool. A checkbox has the same purpose, but doesn't look like that at all. I get what you're going for, though. The graphic reminds me of a phone interface on-off switch which looks pretty neat I guess.

Comment: I agree with @chris, you are just representing a boolean state - which traditionally is what check boxes are for.  You may have to create your own unless you can find a 3rd party one.

Comment: QComboBox might be a good option, though it doesn't display all options at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [QSlider](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qslider.html), setting it's minimum value to 0, it's maximum value to 1 and the steps to one, such that only two values are possible.

Comment: While this is a total overkill it is about the easiest solution and the look is not too bad. The only alternative would be the mentioned Checkbox but since I hvae just fruitlessly passed 15min searching for a decent switch icon which looks good if flipped as well I opt for the slider

Comment: It's not very user friendly, as clicking does not toggle the state.

Comment: It does if you use the valueChanged( int ) signal.